# Why value is "Undefined" after passing to controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

I am not sure why `console.log` says undefined

```
$scope.onSizeSelected = function(productId, sizeQtyPrice){
  console.log('size selected ...' + sizeQtyPrice);
  $scope.updateSelectedProductBySizeSelected(productId ,sizeQtyPrice);
};
```

My html `div` tag:

```
<div ng-show="product[0].sizeQtyPrice[0].size > 0" ng-init="onSizeSelected(product[0].id, product[0].sizeQtyPrice[0])" >Select a Size</div>
```

My `http` inside controller:

```
$http.get("/get_product_details/?prod_id=1")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.product = response;
        }).error(function(){
            console.log('Error happened ... ');
        });
```

`product` gets below `response`:

```
[
{
    "selectedQtyOptions": [],
    "selectedSize": "",
    "description": "taxiing",
    "selectedQty": "1",
    "title": "nationally",
    "brand": "Brand2",
    "product_identifier_type": "SKU",
    "images": [
        {
            "image0": "/media/products/bb61e8ae422b736ff6c1b9562cbde883.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "sizeQtyPrice": [
        {
            "discountAttributes": "Jung fords redskin richest pearl paperweight careen confides backstage gushing",
            "measureUnit": "mm",
            "discountPercent": 5,
            "mrp": 8269,
            "qty": 2,
            "size": 62
        },
        {
            "discountAttributes": "snitched wisps unambiguously harshest clothed famished spec triathlon Ethelred addicts",
            "measureUnit": "Kg",
            "discountPercent": 10,
            "mrp": 5644,
            "qty": 6,
            "size": 92
        },
        {
            "discountAttributes": "committal forming Welsh mawkishly swapped merchandize brawn demises emailed UCLA",
            "measureUnit": "Kg",
            "discountPercent": 3,
            "mrp": 7106,
            "qty": 5,
            "size": 32
        }
    ],
    "product_identifier": "8e4e9389-6c46-4dc8-8716-0c7d2e580d3e",
    "id": 1
}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that : 
`onSizeSelected` gets called before the ajax returns.

```
$http.get("/get_product_details/?prod_id=1")
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.product = response;
             //<------------ set here the data
        }).error(function(){
            console.log('Error happened ... ');
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked but can u help me in using `promise` over here. I read abt it, but as a newbee I cant figure out how to use it here(i mean with ng-init) .  can u please help